# Web app not working on IPad but works on desktop browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser, css, ipad

I am creating a web application that runs on an ipad using JQuery, CSS and HTML, when i test my application on a web browser everything works perfectly, but when i access the web app through the ipads browser all the windows look the same but none of the functionality is there. I have no idea why because i have all the .js files imported into the .html files and all the functionality works on the safari and fire on the desktop.... It is as if the web app on the ipad is ignoring all my .js files!

here is a picture of my files and i can add code if anybody wants it

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas why the functionality would not be working on the ipad?

Comment: What doesn't work? drag and drop? Do you have a public URL so we could take a look? it's hard just by looking at files...

Comment: Maybe there is a path problem when you include all your .js files. The Markup would be nice to see.

Comment: is javascript enabled on your ipad?

Comment: Check that the ipad is connected to the internet or network that the web server is on. Can you view your project on another computer other than your desktop or your ipad?

Comment: What is the functionality that isn't working? It could be something you can't do on iPad... like mouseover

Comment: All the validation for the application isnt working. Like you have to enter the correct id at the start and you have to fill in all the details in the 2nd page to continue. All these work in the web browser on the desktop but not on the ipad. Ya i have javascript enabled on the ipad and i can access it from other computers aswel so thats not the problem. I think the problem is that when the project is built, it is in the folder of another application with a folder called 'js' and .js classes that are named the same. I think the desktop notices that they are diff but the ipad does not

Comment: I finally managed to solve the problem, i had all my files being loaded in an init() method, but the method that was calling this init() method method was never being from the ipad but it was being called from the web browser so that is why i was not able to see an error with this when i debugged this with the browser

Answer (score 2):

You can try to launch the web application on a Webkit browser which is what is used in iPad and try to figure out what the issue is. Webkit browsers include Safari and Google Chrome. Using these launch the Web Inspector and see if there are any errors loading javascript files by going to Network Tab.

Comment: I'm not sure this is helpful. I also have the same issue, on a brand new iPad 3. The asker also specifically mentioned testing, and working, on Safari desktop. My webapp also works in Android 2.3 phone's stock browser, which is much less advanced than iPad 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the remote debuging feature with the ipad and safari.  Warning this only works on IOS 6
http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/